# Using of strip() function

Tags: python, strip

I want to learn what is the difference between two code lines.I couldn't find the difference.Whenever I try to run the second code,it doesn't affect string **a**.

Could someone tell me why the second code line doens't work?

```
a = "aaaaIstanbulaaaa".strip('a')    #Affects the string
print(a)
>>>Istanbul
```

```
a = "aaaaIstanbulaaaa"     #Doesn't affect the string
a.strip('a')
print(a)
>>>aaaaIstanbulaaaa
```

Comment: Strings in Python are immutable. No string function ever modified the original string

Answer (score 5):

`str.strip` *returns* a value; it does not modify the `str` value invoking it. `str` values are immutable; you cannot modify an existing `str` value in any way.

Answer (score 2):

The `str.strip()` isn't an **inplace** method, it doesn't change the current object you're calling with, it returns a new one modified

That is an example of inplace modification

```
x = [1, 2, 3]
x.append(4)

# x is [1, 2, 3, 4]
```